# Cognito admin_initiate_auth responds with exception User does not exist when creating a new user

Tags: ruby, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to create a new user in a Cognito user pool from my ruby backend server. Using this code:

```
client = Aws::CognitoIdentityProvider::Client.new
response = client.admin_initiate_auth({
  auth_flow: 'ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH',
  auth_parameters: {
    'USERNAME': @user.email,
    'PASSWORD': '123456789'
  },
  client_id: ENV['AWS_COGNITO_CLIENT_ID'],
  user_pool_id: ENV['AWS_COGNITO_POOL_ID']
})
```

The response I get is `Aws::CognitoIdentityProvider::Errors::UserNotFoundException: User does not exist`.

I'm trying to follow the Server Authentication Flow (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-authentication-flow.html), and from that I understood that I could create a new user using `admin_initiate_auth`.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong method. `admin_initiate_auth` is for logging in/authenticating a user with the `ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH` turned on.

You need to use the `sign_up` method:

```
resp = client.sign_up({
  client_id: "ClientIdType", # required
  secret_hash: "SecretHashType",
  username: "UsernameType", # required
  password: "PasswordType", # required
  user_attributes: [
    {
      name: "AttributeNameType", # required
      value: "AttributeValueType",
    },
  ],
  validation_data: [
    {
      name: "AttributeNameType", # required
      value: "AttributeValueType",
    },
  ],
  analytics_metadata: {
    analytics_endpoint_id: "StringType",
  },
  user_context_data: {
    encoded_data: "StringType",
  },
})
```

You can find it in the [AWS Cognito IDP docs here.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/CognitoIdentityProvider/Client.html#sign_up-instance_method)